# Dandelion graphQl endpoints not working?

Tags: blockchain, cardano-graphql

I'am was trying to use these endpoints to use playground of cardano graphQL ( https://graphql-api.mainnet.dandelion.link/ ) and (https://graphql-api.testnet.dandelion.link/) but none is working, they are giving 503 and 403 errors

Are they shut down permanently ?

Answer (score 1):

probably related: https://twitter.com/DandelionLink/status/1667281153764515841?t=d2O7q8eowxyFfVUJ4kF-cQ&s=19

It is likely just internal maintainance